# What are the techniques to finding type of discontinuity without graphing?

Tags: functions, continuity

An example would be $f(x)=\frac{x-2}{|x-1|}$

I know that there will be a discontinuity at x=1 as it would make it undefined, but I'm not sure how to determine the type of discontinuity outside of graphing it.

My guess here would be that it is simply a removeable discontinuity at x=1.

Answer (score 2):

A function $f$ has a removable discontinuity at $x_0$ when it has a finite limit at that point:

$$\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=L<\infty.$$

In your example, $f$ does not have a finite limit as $x\to 1$. Instead $f$ has a vertical asymptote at $x=1$:

$$\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)=-\infty.$$

Comment: This helps me understand when to spot a removeable discontinuity. Thank you.

Comment: @user312484 no prob